# Is there a way to specify name servers for an interface in lxc configuration?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, linux-networking, lxc, resolv.conf

I'm trying to make LXC containers use static IP addresses. For that I specify

```
lxc.network.ipv4 = 10.0.3.3
lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 10.0.3.1
```

in `lxc` config file. I have only loopback interface in `/etc/network/interfaces` in containers. And it mostly works. Except for domain name resolution. Is there a way to do something similar to what `dns-nameservers` stanza in `/etc/network/interfaces` does in `lxc` config file?

For now I'm considering to move network settings inside container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up having:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.3.2
gateway 10.0.3.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

in `/etc/network/interfaces`. With `/var/lib/lxc/*/config` being:

```
...
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.link = lxcbr0
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:d6:21:a6
```